# How do I get DataGridView comboboxes to display their drop down list in one click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

After I set "EditOnEnter" to be true, the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` still takes two clicks to open if I don't click on the down arrow part of the combo box.

Anyone have any clue how to fix this? I've got my own `DataGridView` class that I use, so I can easily fix this issue system-wide with a few smart event handlers I hope.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Since you already have the `DataGridView`'s `EditMode` property set to "EditOnEnter", you can just override its [`OnEditingControlShowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.oneditingcontrolshowing.aspx) method to make sure the drop-down list is shown as soon as a combo box receives focus:**

```
public class myDataGridView : DataGridView
{

    protected override void OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEditingControlShowing(e);

        if (e.Control is ComboBox) {
            SendKeys.Send("{F4}");
        }
    }

}
```

Whenever an edit control in your `DataGridView` control gets the input focus, the above code checks to see if it is a combo box. If so, it [virtually "presses"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) the F4 key, which causes the drop-down portion to expand (try it when any combo box has the focus!). It's a little bit of a hack, but it works like a charm.

Comment: I've already got lots of 'hacks' in that datagridview class of mine. One more isn't going to hurt. I'll try this out today.

Comment: I just hope this someday doesn't get in the way of my plan to use the F-Keys to switch between tabs.

Comment: @IsaacB: You'll have to be careful using F-Keys to switch between tabs either way. Certain F-Keys have pre-defined uses in Windows that you probably shouldn't override. Like the above demonstrates, whenever any combo box has focus, F4 will cause it to drop down. F10 always activates the application's menu system.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I'm pretty green at all of this.

Comment: This isn't really the whole solution, if on editing control showing will fire in times other than when they click on the box, such as if you click on another tab in the tab control and click back to the original tab, or sort the dgv when the combobox is the first column in the list etc. It just opened up a bigger can of worms.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cellclick event doesn't fire very reliably when clicking on comboboxes either :(

Comment: @IsaacB: I suppose that's true. There are cases where this behavior might not be appropriate, but you're trying to do something non-standard: Combo boxes are not designed to drop down when they get the focus. And with the territory comes some tradeoffs and unexpected behaviors. I assume the reason the `CellClick` event doesn't work is it only fires when the cell is...clicked, not when it gets the focus using the tab key.

Comment: I'm still using this trick though, I'm just adding little hacks to fix the unexpected behaviors as they arise. I guess that's the nature of the datagridview...

Answer (score 4):

I used this solution as it avoids sending keystrokes:

Override the OnCellClick method (if you're subclassing) or subscribe to the CellClick event (if you're altering the DGV from another object rather than as a subclass).

```
protected override void OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Normally the user would need to click a combo box cell once to 
    // activate it and then again to drop the list down--this is annoying for 
    // our purposes so let the user activate the drop-down with a single click.
    if (e.ColumnIndex == this.Columns["YourDropDownColumnName"].Index
        && e.RowIndex >= 0
        && e.RowIndex <= this.Rows.Count)
    {
        this.CurrentCell = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        this.BeginEdit(false);
        ComboBox comboBox = this.EditingControl as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }

    base.OnCellContentClick(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected override void OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEditingControlShowing(e);
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl != null)
        {
            dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.GotFocus += this.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl_GotFocus;
            dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.Disposed += this.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl_Disposed;
        }
    }

    private void DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            if (!comboBox.DroppedDown)
            {
                comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.GotFocus -= this.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl_GotFocus;
            control.Disposed -= this.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl_Disposed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A little explanation of your answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the SendKeys issues, try the solution from [Open dropdown(in a datagrid view) items on a single click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342334/open-dropdownin-a-datagrid-view-items-on-a-single-click).  Essentially, in OnEditingControlShowing hook to the Enter event of the combo box, in the Enter event handler, set ComboBox.DroppedDown = true.  That seems to have the same effect, but without the side effects @Cody Gray mentions.