# DataGridviewComboBox requires 2 clicks to show the list of items

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open dropdown(in a datagrid view) items on a single click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342334/open-dropdownin-a-datagrid-view-items-on-a-single-click)

We have a DataGridView where one column is a ComboBox with the DropDownButton style. The DataGridView is in FullRowSelect mode. Let's assume that I have 5 rows, and row 0 is selected in the DataGridView.

I want to select an item from the ComboBox of -say for example- row 2, therefore I click the little arrow of the ComboBox. When I do this, first, row 2 of the DataGridView is selected. The ComboBox does not open yet. Only the second click opens the ComboBox.

In fact, it used to require 3 clicks, but then we overloaded the CellMouseDown to do:

```
myDataGridView.ClearSelection();
myDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
```

With this, we're down to 2 clicks. Is there a way to show the ComboBox items with one click only?

Edit: I should also mention that, instead of clicking on the little arrow of the ComboBox, if I click the ComboBox itself, it takes 3 clicks to show the ComboBox items!

Comment: You can check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342334/open-dropdownin-a-datagrid-view-items-on-a-single-click/6342462#6342462)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it first focus or select the cell, and then on second click it opens the dropdown. To solve this issue, check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/c461b774-ece5-4fdd-86c5-90e5b6426690/).

Answer (score 10):

Set your DataGridView's [EditMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode%28VS.90%29.aspx) to [EditOnEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditmode%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)