# Associate two classes so a combobox appears with the second class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, datagridview, combobox

I have a Winforms application. There are two classes. One class stores the people that contribute to a book. The other class is a list of possible contribution types (like editor, reviewer, and so on).

The *BookContributors* class is the datasource for my datagridview and that works just fine. Now, I want to have the *BookContributorTypes* class be a combobox that feeds the *BookContributors* class.

So far in my reading, it looks like I have a number of options, including forcing a combobox into the datagridview, using class attributes, creating a 1-to-many relationship between classes.

Since my code will have many of these types of situations, I want to do this right. I think this means showing the relationship between the two classes somehow so the datagridview knows to just display the combobox, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

BookContributors is populated by a person filling out a contributor. Example:
BookContributor = "John Smith"; BookContributorFileAs="Smith, John"; BookContributorType = "rev".

```
public class BookContributors : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bookContributor;
    [DescriptionLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorComment")]
    [DisplayNameLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorDisplayName")]
    public string BookContributor
    {
        get { return _bookContributor; }
        set
        {
            if (SetField(ref _bookContributor, value, "BookContributor"))
            {
                // When the user types an author name, add the sorted name to the sorted field.
                //  ex Name = William E Raymond
                //  ex File As = Raymond, William E
                var name = _bookContributor.Split(' ');
                if (name.Length >= 2)
                {
                    string fileAsName = (name[name.Length - 1] + ",");
                    for (int i = 0; i <= (name.Length - 2); i++)
                    {
                        fileAsName = fileAsName + " " + name[i];
                    }
                    BookContributorFileAs = fileAsName;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string _bookContributorFileAs;
    [DescriptionLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorFileAsComment")]
    [DisplayNameLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorFileAsDisplayName")]
    public string BookContributorFileAs { get { return _bookContributorFileAs; } set { SetField(ref _bookContributorFileAs, value, "BookContributorFileAs"); } }

    private string _bookContributorType;
    [DescriptionLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorTypeComment")]
    [DisplayNameLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorTypeDisplayName")]
    public string BookContributorType { get { return _bookContributorType; } set { SetField(ref _bookContributorType, value, "BookContributorType"); } }


    #region handle property changes
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        //if the value did not change, do nothing.
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        //the value did change, so make the modification.
        field = value;
        return true;
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

BookContributorTypes (populated with a list of bookContributor types from an XML file). Example Book contributor type ID's: "rev", "edt". Example Book contributor type descriptions: "Reviewer", "Editor".

```
class BookContributorTypes : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bookContributorTypeId;
    [DescriptionLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorTypeIdComment_lkp")]
    [DisplayNameLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorTypeIdDisplayName_lkp")]
    public string BookContributorTypeId { get { return _bookContributorTypeId; } set { SetField(ref _bookContributorTypeId, value, "BookContributorTypeId"); } }

    private string _bookContributorTypeDescription;
    [DescriptionLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorTypeComment_lkp")]
    [DisplayNameLocalized(typeof(ResourcesClassBooks), "BookContributorTypeDisplayName_lkp")]
    public string BookContributorTypeDescription { get { return _bookContributorTypeDescription; } set { SetField(ref _bookContributorTypeDescription, value, "BookContributorTypeDescription"); } }


    #region handle property changes
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        //if the value did not change, do nothing.
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        //the value did change, so make the modification.
        field = value;
        return true;
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

All I have working right now, without the combo box, because I do not know how to implement a combobox to show the selection options from the BookContributorTypes class:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bookContributors;
```

Thanks for ay help you can provide.

Comment: What you have so far? Show working code which you used at this moment. And please explain what is the different between "quick fix" and "good repeatable process".

Comment: Hi there. I added the working classes, which is not much more detail. The only 'working' code I have for the datagridview at the moment is just connecting the datasource to one class. I have clarified my question in the latest edit but to directly respond to your "quick fix" vs. "good repeatable process", I mean the following: Since my code will have many of these types of situations, I want to do this right. I think this means showing the relationship between the two classes somehow so the datagridview knows to just display the combobox, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with WinForms `DataGridView` for several years. AFAIK the `DataGridView` is not as smart
as you expect. You have to setup comboBox columns manually,
i.e. on event `DataBindingComplete`

- create new `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`
- set its `DataPropertyName` property to `"BookContributorType"`
- add it to `DataGridViewColumnCollection`
- set its `DataSource` property to a collection of `BookContributorTypes`
- set its `ValueMember` property to `"BookContributorTypeId"`
- set its `DisplayMember` property to `"BookContributorTypeDescription"`
- adopt properties from auto-generated column corresponding `BookContributorTypes` like
  `DisplayIndex`
- remove auto-generated column

I'm using wrapper classes around `DataGridView` to get a smarter control. In this way I've reduced
source code everywhere I'm using `DataGridView`.

Here is a code snippet to replace an auto-generated column with a comboBox column:

```
DataGridViewColumn auto // = ... auto-generated column to be replaced
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combo.DataPropertyName = auto.DataPropertyName;
combo.Name = auto.Name;
DataGridView dgv = auto.DataGridView;
dgv.Columns.Add(combo);

combo.DataSource = GetBookContributorTypes; // collection of comboBox entries
combo.ValueMember = "BookContributorTypeId";
combo.DisplayMember = "BookContributorTypeDescription";

// adopt further properties if required
combo.Frozen = auto.Frozen;
combo.DisplayIndex = auto.DisplayIndex;
combo.Visible = auto.Visible;
combo.ReadOnly = auto.ReadOnly;
combo.HeaderText = auto.HeaderText;
combo.HeaderCell.ToolTipText = auto.HeaderCell.ToolTipText;
combo.SortMode = auto.SortMode;
combo.Width = auto.Width;

dgv.Columns.Remove(auto);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I feel like there is something missing here. There is a primary DataGridView datasource called `BookContributors`. There is a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with a datasource called `BookContributorTypes`. How does the combobox column know where to feed the selected item back to the appropriate property of the primary datasource? Do you happen to have a code sample? Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out and posted an answer.

Comment: @Bill: You're right. I missed `DataPropertyName`. I've completed my answer for further reading.

Comment: Do you remove the auto-generated column or hide it? When I tested the `remove` method, it simply takes the column and moves it to the end of the datagridview and [I think] disconnects it from the class. I used `Visible=false` to remove it but am not sure if that will cause problems down the road.

Comment: @Bill: I `Remove` the auto-generated column, but after adding comboBox columns. I wasn't aware that
auto-generation takes place between `Remove` and `Add`. I've corrected my answer and added a
code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a lot more difficult to research than I originally thought. It turns out, if you want to place a column in a DataGridView with a combobox and have that combobox interact with another class, it is not a quick one-liner.

My example has two classes:

- `BookContributors` (`bookContributors`) - A list of people that have contributed to a book. For example, this stores a person's name and the type of contribution they made.
- `BookContributorTypes` (`bookContributorTypes`) - A list of possible types of contributions to a book, like *Editor* or *Contributor*.
- I want the `ContributorTypes` class to be a combobox and store the user's selection into the `BookContributors` class, specifically the `BookContributorType` property.

Here is the code I came up with, along with some additional notes I found along the way. To the best of my knowledge, the information I provide is accurate :-)

```
    gvContributors.DataSource = bookContributors; //set the datgridview's datasource so it displays the class you want.
    gvContributors.Columns["BookContributorType"].Visible = false; //hide the column (property) you want to replace with a combobox.

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn contribType = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(); //create a combobox object.
    contribType.HeaderText = "My Column"; //the text to display in the column header.
    contribType.Name = "BookContributorType"; //name of the class property you set to Visible=false. Note sure if this is needed.
    contribType.DataSource = bookContributorTypes; //name of the class that provides the combobox data.
    contribType.DisplayMember = "BookContributorTypeDescription"; //data the user will see when clicking the combobox.
    contribType.ValueMember = "BookContributorTypeId"; //data to store in the class property.
    contribType.DataPropertyName = "BookContributorType"; //the class property you are binding to in order to store the data.

    gvContributors.Columns.Add(contribType); //add the new combobox to the datagridview.
```

What you have now is the following:

1. A `DataGridView` with a datasource. In my case, the datasource is a class.
2. A hidden (`Visible=false`) column that you want to make a combobox.
3. A `DataGridViewComboBox` that links to another datasource so the user will see a list of values. By using the `DataPropertyName` as the same name as the hidden column, you are now binding to the DataGridView's `DataSource`.

Another answer on this post suggests you `Remove` the column you are replacing with a combobox but `Visible=false` seems to work for me.

When you run the solution, you will find the user has to click twice on the combobox. I have not tried this code yet, but think this post will resolve that problem: [Open dropdown(in a datagrid view) items on a single click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342334/open-dropdownin-a-datagrid-view-items-on-a-single-click)