# C# Can't reflect into private field

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, reflection, managed

I got an issue.

In Unity I want to reflect into a private field. But I always get null for the fieldinfo. what am I doing wrong?

```
public abstract class _SerializableType
{
    [SerializeField] private string name;
}

// because I am using a CustomPropertyDrawer for all inherited from _SerializeType
public class SerializableType<T> : _SerializableType { }
public class SerializableType : _SerializableType { }

[Serializable] public class CTech : SerializableType<_CouplingTechnology> { }
```

so using this method should actually work.

```
        // type is CTech
        // propertyPath in that case is "name"
        FieldInfo info = type.GetField(propertyPath, BindingFlags.Instance
                         | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am calling this method in a managed library that has its own CustomInspector. so it reflects into every field and figure how to display it. AppDomain is fullyTrusted. I don't know what else could be of importance...

Comment: variable `type` is `typeof(_SerializableType)` ?

Comment: In addition to what @AntonKomyshan said, the variable `propertyPath` should also be the string "name"?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan yep type is of _SerializeType ( got through the Iterator of seriliazedObject) told you it's more complicated ;-)
SteveDanner I put than in...

Comment: What is `type` here? If it's not `_SerializableType` then you will not be able to see the private field, even the derived class isn't aware of it.

Comment: it actually is part of     [Serializable] public class CTech : SerializableType<_CouplingTechnology> { }
because unity's serialization is damn shallow. how about the subclass?

Comment: The comments shows that you need to post some more code. Show how `type` is declared. Also, hardcode "name" to `propertyPath` and see what happens

Comment: type actually is             Type type = GetEligibleObjectType(property.serializedObject, parentPath);
 told you it gets complicated. And i'm printing it's full name, which tells me it is a CTech

Comment: Like I said, a derived class doesn't have a private field from a base class.

Comment: You replied to @AntonKomyshan 's comment wit yes which is actually false.

Comment: @Programmer, yeah, so implicit conversion doesn't work here you say?

Comment: @DavidG so, how am I going to get a private field that is inherited from another class?

Comment: You need to show us how you're getting `type`.  Saying it's complicated doesn't help us help you.  It does the opposite.  We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to get a private field that is declared in a base class from a derived type is to go up the class hierarchy. So for example, you could do something like this:

```
public FieldInfo GetPrivateFieldRecursive(Type type, string fieldName)
{
    FieldInfo field = null;

    do
    {
        field = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public 
            | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField);
        type = type.BaseType;

    } while(field == null && type != null);

    return field;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to ensure that your object is actually of the desired type and then call `GetField` on the right type object.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new SerializableType();
        // reflection version of "obj is _SerializableType":
        if(typeof(_SerializableType).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
        {
            var info = typeof(_SerializableType).GetField("name", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var name = info.GetValue(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

    }
}

public abstract class _SerializableType
{
    public string name = "xyz";
}

public class SerializableType : _SerializableType { }
```

Comment: hey champ, thanks for the answer. But i need seomthing more flexible, like @DavidG s answer. because of: _I am calling this method in a managed library that has its own CustomInspector. so it reflects into every field and figure how to display it._